# jQuery not calculating and displaying the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I been working on this for awhile and it's not taking the input that get the balance of a credit card debt and keep giving me an error.

Also it's not executing the while function to give me the results to display. A fresh pair of eyes would be helpful in finding the errors.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/to0namiSB/QVCHT/8/)

```
if (!isValid(currentBalance, 0, 10000)) {
            return false
         } else if (!isValid(interest, 0, 30)) {
            return false
         } else {
            return true;
         }

         if (!isValid(mnth_pay, currentBalance*.02, currentBalance)) {
            return false
       } else {
            var balance = $("#sliderOutput12").val();       // used in loop
            var interest = $("#sliderOutput13").val() / 100;
            var mnth_pay =  $("#sliderOutput14").val();

            var currentBalance = balance.val();


            var financeCharge = 0;          // finance charge
            var numberMonths = 0;
            var totalInterest = 0;
     }



      while (currentBalance > 0) {
        financeCharge = currentBalance*interest/12;
        currentBalance = currentBalance - mnth_pay + financeCharge;
        numberMonths++;
                if (numberMonths > 300) {
            alert("We are interrupting this process to prevent a hang which may result with a very high balance, high interest rate and low monthly payment.\n\nTry entering a higher monthly payment amount." )
                    mnth_pay.focus()
                    mnth_pay.select()
                    return
          }
        totalInterest += financeCharge;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checkin for the value of `currentBalance` before actually getting its value:

```
if (!isValid(currentBalance, 0, 10000)) {
```

Also, you have an error here:

```
var balance = $("#sliderOutput12").val();       // used in loop

var currentBalance = balance.val();
```

Technically, you're doing this: `var currentBalance = $("#sliderOutput12").val().val();`

I've fixed those in your code (by just moving the variable definitions to the top of the calculate function), see if you can work it out from here: http://jsfiddle.net/QVCHT/10/

And one more thing. Any code below this part:

```
     if (!isValid(currentBalance, 0, 10000)) {
        return false
     } else if (!isValid(interest, 0, 30)) {
        return false
     } else {
        return true;
     }
```

Will never get executed since no matter what happens, that part returns something (which "ends" the function). You probably want to get rid of that last return.

Here is the final version: http://jsfiddle.net/ypt0c8ep/

Comment: so move the variables outside of the function?

Comment: No need to, just define them before you use them. If they were outside, you'd still need to read them again inside the function to get the current values. See the final version in my answer.

Comment: if (!isValid(mnth_pay, currentBalance*.02, currentBalance)) {
       return false
       } else {
       var balance = $("#sliderOutput12").val();  // used in loop
     var interest = $("#sliderOutput13").val() / 100; //(form.interest.value/100);
     var mnth_pay =  $("#sliderOutput14").val();

     var currentBalance = balance.val();


     var financeCharge = 0;   // finance charge
     var numberMonths = 0;
     var totalInterest = 0;
     }

Comment: also it's on the jsfiddle i believe

Comment: No problem, don't forget to vote/accept the answer for this so it's no longer open.